# So, i'm trying to knit a document with R-markdown as usual and i keep getting the same: (it is likely that you forgot to quote "character" options)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

This is my chunk. I looked at the recomended page, and tried what I could. I don´t know how to fix it and knit it successfully:

````
```{r 2a, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE }}

tokio <- read.csv("tokio_2021.csv", header = TRUE)
tokio <- tokio%>%arrange(country)

media_pob_gdp <- mean(tokio$gdp_pc)
media_pob_poblacion <- mean(tokio$population)

muestra.paises_AM <- tokio$country[1:128]

tokio_AM <- tokio%>%filter(country %in% muestra.paises_AM)
mean(tokio_AM$gdp_pc)

alpha <- 0.05
n <- length(tokio_AM$gdp_pc)
xBarra <- mean(tokio_AM$gdp_pc)
s <- sd(tokio_AM$gdp_pc)

lim_inf <- xBarra - (s/sqrt(n))*(qt(1-alpha/2,n-1))
lim_sup <- xBarra + (s/sqrt(n))*(qt(1-alpha/2,n-1))
IC_gdp <- c(lim_inf, lim_sup)
IC_gdp

```
````

at some point it gives 128 names as characters, so i suspect there's a problem printing that or some instruction to print them is missing. It CAN run te last variables and print a number, but I cant knit it whichever the case.

This is the whole error:

```
processing file: Tarea1_MA_entr.Rmd
(*) NOTE: I saw chunk options "2a, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE }"
 please go to https://yihui.org/knitr/options
 (it is likely that you forgot to quote "character" options)
Error in parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:67: unexpected '}'
1: alist( '2a', echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE }
                                                                      ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_params -> withCallingHandlers -> eval -> parse_only -> parse
Execution halted
```

Thank you,

Comment: The error doesn't appear to come from the inside of the chunk but rather the outside. Can you show us the backticks and etc around this chunk?

Comment: omg i've been going around this for an hour. Thanks to your answer I was able to focus and freshly look at the sintaxis. It ws a dumb one, I repeated a }. Thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I thought I would post my problem and solution in case someone has the same issue; in my case, I had a typo when I set `fig.width = 15t` (note the trailing t after the 15). In this case I had the same error as above but with `alist( 'argument 1', 'argument 2', ...,  fig.height=15t^`. Removing the `t` fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if you have mistakenly typed the closing brace twice, e.g.

````
```{r 2a, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE } }
````

There are probably other ways to get it; if this doesn't look like what you did, please post the actual code you used.

Comment: Shamefully, I did. Thank you! I've been going through his for more than an hour and I couldn't see anything wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: I just recognized it because I'm used to looking at syntax error messages :-).